# "section" in UICollectionView's indexPath

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

In UITableView, I can see these in .h file:

```
@interface NSIndexPath (UITableView)

+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section;

@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger section;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger row;

@end
```

In UICollectionView, I can find this category:

```
@interface NSIndexPath (UICollectionViewAdditions)

+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForItem:(NSInteger)item inSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger item NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

@end
```

But, if inside a collectionView's delegate class, I refer "section" property in an indexPath for a collectionView, Xcode gives NO warnings, why?

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)cv numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (cv == self.collectionView) {
        if (cv.collectionViewLayout == self.layout2) {
            return [self.searches count];
        } else {
            NSString *searchTerm = self.searches[section];
            return [self.searchResults[searchTerm] count];
        }
    } else if (cv == self.currentPinchCollectionView) {
       //commend for below == @property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *currentPinchedItem;
        NSString *searchTerm = self.searches[self.currentPinchedItem.section];// this "section" is NOT for tableView, why NO warning/error from Xcode?
        return [self.searchResults[searchTerm] count];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the IndexPath object is created in the UITableView.h. The item property is then added on a category of IndexPath in the UICollectionView.h since a row property has no meaning inside a collection view. But still, section is an available property everywhere in the framework because that's the whole point of an indexpath.

Comment: Thanks Kujey! cold you show me any prove (in Documentation or .h file) that "section is an available property everywhere in the framework "?